# Does OpenJ9 support sun.misc.Contended annotation?

Tags: java, ibm-jvm, openj9

I've created a program to check if `@sun.misc.Contended` is in effect. The idea is that when `@Contended` is in effect, the field offsets in annotated class will be larger.

I can see the expected difference in offsets on OpenJDK, if I specify the `-XX:-RestrictContended` flag. I do not see any difference on OpenJ9 11 (jdk-11.0.1+13, Eclipse OpenJ9 VM-11.0.1) through.

The OpenJDK output is

```
readOnly: 12
writeOnly: 16
----
readOnly: 12
writeOnly: 144
```

The OpenJ9 output is

```
readOnly: 8
writeOnly: 12
----
readOnly: 8
writeOnly: 12
```

The program is

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class Main {
    public static class Baseline {
        int readOnly;
        int writeOnly;
    }

    public static class Contended {
        int readOnly;

        @sun.misc.Contended
        int writeOnly;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Baseline b = new Baseline();
        Contended s = new Contended();

        printOffsets(b);
        System.out.println("----");
        printOffsets(s);
    }

    // https://blog.hazelcast.com/using-sun-misc-unsafe-in-java-9/
    @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
    private static Unsafe getUnsafe() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field singleoneInstanceField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        singleoneInstanceField.setAccessible(true);
        return (Unsafe) singleoneInstanceField.get(null);
    }

    // http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/
    public static void printOffsets(Object o) throws Exception {
        Unsafe u = getUnsafe();
        Class c = o.getClass();
        for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if ((f.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) == 0) {
                printOffset(u, f);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printOffset(Unsafe u, Field f) {
            long offset = u.objectFieldOffset(f);
            System.out.println(f.getName() + ": " + offset);
    }
}
```

Comment: helpful discussion on OpenJ9 chat https://openj9.slack.com/archives/C862YFGL9/p1542383521060200

Comment: feature request https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/issues/3716

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, OpenJ9 supports `@Contended` at the class level only.